# Binary with Decimal Place to 2s Complement

Tags: binary

What is the decimal value of the following 8-bit two’s complement binary number?

1001.1110

Can we do it the normal method?

ex. Since negative we flip bits 0110.0001

Then add 1.

0110.0001 + 1 = 0110.0010

0(2^3) + 1(2^2) + 1(2^1) + 0(2^0) + 0(2^-1) + 0(2^-2) + 1(2^-3) + 0(2^-4) = -6.125?